Australia tourist visa application form
Hi I am an Indian passport holder applying for australia tourist visa. While filling the application form there is a question about previous visa rejection. My schengen visa was rejected on Feb 2020. I am ticking that option yes and just mentioning that schengen visa was rejected in Feb 2020.
Schengen visa rejection was for two reasons 1. Purpose of travel and 2. No strong ties to home country.
I later realized that I mentioned wrong travel dates in my cover letter. I own a property now and I have much much investment in mutual fund as compared to Feb 2020. My salary has also increased since Feb 2020.
Should I write any explanation in my cover letter for schengen visa rejection?

Why would you not provide an explanation?

Because I am applying for australia visa not schengen visa. Just confused if this will be too much information. In the application form I am writing the reason of rejection. Is writing explanation in Cover letter recommend??

You don’t give enough information in your question to enable anyone to provide a meaningful answer. Please edit it to include the information in your comment, the reason for the Schengen rejection, and what has changed since then that addresses the refusal reason.

I have edited it now.

I later realized that I mentioned wrong travel dates in my cover letter. Is this the wrong dates for the Schengen rejection, or the current trip? How wrong were they? If you mention something slightly wrong for the previous visa rejection, it's unlikely to be significant.

Wrong travel dates were for schengen visa. I was visiting turkey first and 3 days later I was going to Greece. But in my cover letter I mentioned start date as turkey start date not the date on which I was entering Greece. I haven't yet applied for Australia visa.
